# Use PrismJS with RequireJS, even though it's not a dependency

Tags: requirejs, amd, prism.js

I'm trying to use PrismJS while not attaching it as a strict dependency to any functions. All iI needed it to do is render the syntax highlighting on the page but, unfortunately, the full styling isn't being passed to the page.

I did read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168816/loading-non-amd-modules-with-require-js) and confirmed that `Prism` is attached to the `window` object, but the styling isn't showing up on the page.

Here's my code (`prism.css` is concatenated with other styles via Sass):

The HTML:

```
<pre><code class="language-css">
git rm 'myFile.html'
</code></pre>`
```

The script tag:

`<script data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/require.js"></script>`

config.js

```
requirejs.config({

  baseUrl: "/js",

  deps: ["prism"],

  paths: {
    prism: "vendor/prism"
  },

  shim: {
    "prism": {
      "exports": "Prism"
    }
  }
});
```

prism.js

```
define("prism", ["prism"],function(Prism) {
  return Prism; //probably redundant
});
```

I have a feeling that doing something in `prism.js` is what's needed, but am not 100% sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement TinyMCE with Require.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349513/how-can-i-implement-tinymce-with-require-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you don't need this anymore, but I have stumbled on this question while faced with similar problem.

What you need, most likely, is `Prism.highlightAll();` function call. My solution was found at http://schier.co/blog/2013/01/07/how-to-re-run-prismjs-on-ajax-content.html.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that...I should've followed up with an answer, but you beat me to it!